# Theme color SystemChromeMediumColor isn't changing after change of device theme (dark/light)

Tags: xaml, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a problem with using theme color from ThemeResources named SystemChromeMediumColor. No matter what color is set on device, the color is still #FF1F1F1F instead of #FFE6E6E6 (for light theme). According to [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt187274.aspx) it should be changing depending on device theme settings. All other colors (main background color SystemChromeMediumColor is always dark.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set somewhere the *RequestedTheme* property - for example for standard blank app, as I have checked it's set to `RequestedTheme="Light"` for the whole application in *App.xaml* file. When this is set the app won't update theme resources after changes in settings - it simply uses the chosen requested value.

After removing the mentioned line, the simple basic template should work for example with *TextBlock* declared like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="TestValue" FontSize="24" >
    <TextBlock.Foreground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{ThemeResource SystemChromeMediumColor}"/>
    </TextBlock.Foreground>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I know that. I removed the RequestedTheme property both from App.xaml and MainPage.xaml before posting this problem. All other colors are changing when I change dark theme to light.

Comment: @JanChalupa Oh, I see that you already have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it was my mistake. I was editing property to different control.